# Command that can find files that are not referenced by other files and then delete them

Tags: files, grep, rm

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could go about writing a `grep` command that recursively finds files that are not being referenced/used in a specific file and/or a directory of files, and then delete them?

So for example if my file has this

```html
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='path/to/a.css'/>
    <script src='path/to/a-min.js></script>
</head>
```

And my folder has this

```
/assets
-- /css
---- a.css
---- b.css
-- /js
---- a-min.js
---- /b
------ b-min.js
---- /c
------ c-min.js
```

It will recursively delete all the ones not referenced in said file which would be `b.scss`, `b-min.js`, and `c-min.js`. Of course if another file has those files referenced, it wouldn't delete them.

I use version control so it isn't an issue if they get deleted and it screws up but it would be nice if there was a simple command or automated way of doing this correctly. Advice on best practice?

Comment: Parse the HTML with a real parser (perl, python, ruby) and keep a list `reffed` of files referenced, then walk over the list of files and compare to `reffed`

Comment: Hmm I see -- I know html parsing should be done with proper tools. I'll probably explore some options including python. Actually, we're moving most of our stuff to [nodejs which has ways to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977945/html-parser-on-nodejs) so I'm gonna look into that as well.

Comment: Quick and dirty? use grep and either cut or awk to extract the files mentioned by href, sort, uniq, and write to a file.  The use find -type file to find all files, and grep -vf the files not in the html.